# Call back function for $.getJSON() is not working in my spring mvc 3.1.1

Tags: jquery, json, spring-mvc

When i select one value from the drop down , the id value of which i selected is reflecting in my controller and also i'm getting list what i need, but this list not getting in my jsp page.I want to populate this list into my next drop down box without refreshing the page.I think the callback is not working.i'm using spring mvc (3.1.1 RELEASE),jackson 1.9.13. and jdk 1.7 . Is there any compatibility between jdk1.7 and jackson 1.9.13?? .someone please help me.i'm just a beginner..

```
 Controller.java    

         @RequestMapping(value = "listSubcon.htm", method = RequestMethod.GET)
         @ResponseBody
         public List<SubConDetails> sectionList(@RequestParam(value = "prjtId") int prjtId)  { 
            return workOrderService.getsubconDetailsByPrjtId(prjtId);
        }    

    Jsp page  

    $(document).ready(function() {  
     $("#projectDetailsId").change(function()
     $.getJSON("listSubcon.htm", {prjtId:$(this).val() }, function(j) { 
     for(i=0; i < j.lengtht; i++){
           alert("Welcome"+j[i].id);
       }
     });  });  

pom.xml    

<dependency>
<groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
  <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
  <version>1.9.13</version>
 </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's only a copy/paste error, but there are some JS errors on yout code, try this.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#projectDetailsId").change(function() {
        $.getJSON("listSubcon.htm", {
            prjtId: $(this).val()
        }, function(j) {
            for (i = 0; i < j.length; i++) {
                alert("Welcome" + j[i].id);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Still have same issue, callback is not working.Any other suggestions...pls.

Comment: i'm using jdk1.7 ..is there any compatibility between jdk1.7 and jackson 1.9.13 ???